# ListView built dynamically with JSONP data refreshes automatically

Tags: windows-8, winjs

I'm building a Windows 8 Store app in HTML/JS which uses `GeoNames` & `Mediawiki/Wikipedia` APIs.

JSON Data from the `GeoNames` API is populated into a `Listview`. Oddly, the content in the listview refreshes on its own?
Does anyone have any pointers on what could be wrong?

This refresh happens once every minute. While I'm on any other item in the `ListView` than the first, the refresh forces back the focus to the very first item in the list view.

I'm using the `Geolocator PositionChanged event`. I've not set any value explicitly to the `ReportInterval` property of the `Geolocator` class.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have some code that is setting the itemDataSource on the ListView -- is this not because you have some long poll function that is completing, and setting the data again and again?